# Structured database of the ACL Anthology data set?

Tags: computational-linguistics, datasets

Is there any structured database of the ACL Anthology ([former website](https://aclweb.org/anthology/); [new website](http://aclanthology.info/))? By structured database I mean some SQL dump (NoSQL is fine too) that would contain all papers' meta information (venue, date, authors, etc.), and if possible the text as well.

I am aware of the [ACL Anthology Reference Corpus (ACL ARC)](http://acl-arc.comp.nus.edu.sg/) as well as the [ACL Anthology Network (beta)](http://clair.eecs.umich.edu/aan/index.php), but they don't contain database dump.

Comment: [Ulrich Schafer, DFKI](http://www.dfki.de/~uschaefer/) made *ACL Anthology Searchbench*. If you get in touch with him, he may give you what you're looking for.